# Why would you multiply the regression coefficient by the standard deviation of the independent variable?

Tags: interpretation, regression-coefficients

After estimating an OLS regression why would you multiply the coefficient by the standard deviation of the independent variable? Also, how is the interpretation of that different than the interpretation of the coefficient itself?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you supply a context, reference, and/or example?  Otherwise all we can do is speculate.

Comment: Who says you should do this?

Comment: For example, a cross-section regression of future cash flows on current market prices + controls. Then the coefficient on prices is multiplied by the standard deviation of market prices. The construct of interest is the amount of variation in future cash flows explained by current prices.

Comment: gung, it is used in a prior study.

Answer (score 5):

It's not a matter of calculation/theory but really a matter of interpretation of the coefficient. It gives an interpretation of the coefficient somehow **independent of the scale.**

Imagine you express $Y=a+bX$ with OLS. Naively you may want to say : "if the coefficient $b$ of $X$ is large, then $Y$ depends a lot on $X$". Not really.

Assume $X$ is an age expressed as a number of years. You could as well use $X'=\frac{X}{100}$ instead of $X$ : the age expressed as a number of centuries. The result would be $Y=a+b'X'$ with $b'=100b$. Naively, $Y$ seems to depend a lot more on $X'$ than on $X$. This is of course false.

Now, if you look at the coefficient multiplied by the standard deviation, this illusion disappears :

$b'\sigma_{X'}=100 b\frac{\sigma_X}{100}=b\sigma_X$

The coefficient multiplied by the standard deviation represents (intuitively) the "amount" of influence of $X$ on $Y$. It is related to the part of variance explained by $X$.

Comment: If we have a multiple response regression, what will be an equivalent metric as multiplication of coefficient and standard deviation? For example, we're conducting multiple response regression on 10 dependent variables simultaneously, each dependent variable will correspond with a coefficient vector, how do we integrate the interpretation of coefficient for 10 dependent variables together?